# How to cite a film quote using MLA in text citations

Tags: citations, mla, quotes

I am working on an essay, and one of my sources is a film. (The Matrix) What would the in-text citation for the film look like, and would it include the time that the quote occured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site helps you write bibliographies on pretty much any medium: http://www.easybib.com/

Here is the format: 
`Title. Dir. First M. Last. Perf. First M. Last. Distributor, Year Published. Media Type.`

Ex:
`Little Miss Sunshine. Dir. Jonathan Dayton and Valerie Faris. Perf. Greg Kinnear, Steve Carell, Toni Collette, Paul Dano, Abigail Breslin, and Alan Arkin. Fox Searchlight, 2006. DVD.`

Perf is performers.